# count the number of rows in a query

Tags: php, mysql, function, count, pdo

i have this function separated in my working page.

```
public function countRow(){
        $id = $_SESSION['id'];
        $num = 1;
        $query = "SELECT count(*) from `auditsummary` where bizID=? AND statusID=?";
        $sql = $this->db->prepare($query);
        $sql->bindParam(1,$id);
        $sql->bindParam(2,$num);
        $sql->execute();


    }
```

what i'm really trying to do in this function is to count the number of rows that are results of the query but i don't know how to do it and also how to return the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you use a PDOStatement for your query, after the execute, you can use

```
$count = $sql->rowCount();
```

More information:
http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

And to return the result, you can just do:

```
return $count;
```

Information for this:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$query = "SELECT count(*) AS getCount from `auditsummary` where bizID=? AND statusID=?";
```

And get the values as you normally does

```
$count = $row["getCount"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it:

```
$count = "SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE x='x' and y='y'";

$result = $dbconn->prepare($count);
$result->execute();
$t_count = $result->rowCount();

echo $t_count;
```

Comment: where does $pages come from?